# Can't create functions inside a class in Phaser

Tags: javascript, function, methods, phaser-framework

I'm not familiarized with javaScript too much, and I'm starting to do a project in Phaser, at the moment is just a title screen with a button, the issue i'm having is that I'm trying to create another function inside the class but I'm unable to do it, every time I compile I get the error that the function is not defined, in this case the function Carro(), I would really use some help. Thank you.

```
class Inicio extends Phaser.Scene {

constructor(){

    super({key: 'Inicio'});

}

preload(){

    this.load.image('Titulo', 'Assets/Imagenes/LogoInicio.png');
    this.load.spritesheet('Empezar', 'Assets/Imagenes/EmpezarSprites.png', {frameWidth: 393, frameHeight: 117});
    this.load.audio('Dinero', 'Assets/Audio/Dinero.mp3'); }

create(){

    this.add.image(400, 300, 'Titulo');

    var botonEmpezar = this.add.sprite(400, 500, 'Empezar');
    var sonidoDinero = this.sound.add('Dinero');
    var timerCambio;

    botonEmpezar.setInteractive(/*{useHandCursor: true}*/);

    botonEmpezar.on('pointerover', function(){
        this.setFrame(1);
    });

    botonEmpezar.on('pointerout', function(){
        this.setFrame(0);
    });

    botonEmpezar.on('pointerdown', function(){
        this.setFrame(2);
        sonidoDinero.play();
    });

    botonEmpezar.on('pointerup', function(){
        this.setFrame(0);
        //timerCambio = this.scene.time.delayedCall(2000, onEvent(), [], this);
        this.scene.scene.start("Formulario");
    });
        Carro();    
}

Carro(){
    console.log("entro"); }

}
```

This is the config file:

```
window.onload = function(){

    var config = {
        type: Phaser.AUTO,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        backgroundColor: 0x000000,
        scene: [Inicio, Formulario],
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `carro` is a method of `Inicio` class. you need to use `this` keyword to access the method in its class.

```
this.scene.Carro();
```

Example :

```
class test Extends Phaser.Scene {
    create(){
      Carro(); //ERROR
      this.Carro();// OK
      func2(); //OK
    }
    Carro(){
       console.log("Method of test class");
    }
}


 function func2 {
   console.log("function");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I already tried that and didn't work either, I tried again just to check and still is not working. What I get in the console in that case is "this.carro is not a function"

Comment: the way you call the function is wrong. I'll give you some examples

Comment: Thank you so much, I notice my error was because I was calling this.carro inside the button up event. If is not much trouble could you guide me to what would it be the correct way to call the Carro method inside the button up event?. Thank you again, I'm so dumb

Comment: Nevermind, it was this.scene.Carro(). Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy and frustrated. Thank you!!